# Ansible how to reference item in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible

I have a play as follows

```
    - name: create the unison preference file
      template:
      src: default.prf.j2
      dest: /root/.unison/{{ item }}.prf
      with_items: groups['ndeployslaves']
```

The contents of the default.prf.j2 file is as follows

```
    root = /home
    root = ssh://root@{{ item }}//home
    ignore = Path virtfs
    ignore = Path */mail
```

The item variable is not working in the template and I am getting the error

TASK [unison_master : create the unison prefrence file] ************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}

How do I reference an item inside a template used in a play?

Comment: Are you sure that `ndeployslaves` is properly set for your current playbook? Can you add a debug task before the template rendering task and print that variable, just to verify if its content is as you expect?

Comment: I meant printing the content of `groups['ndeployslaves']`

Comment: TASK [unison_master : debug this] **********************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using bare variables is deprecated. Update your playbooks so that the environment value uses the full variable syntax 
('{{groups['ndeployslaves']}}').
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=cpanel.host.net) => {
    "item": "cpanel.sysally.net", 
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
{"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}

Comment: the item has correct value ;just that it cannot be refernced in the jinja2 template as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not letting you use {{item}} in the template, you could do this:

```
- name: create the unison preference file
  copy:
    src: default.prf
    dest: "/root/.unison/{{ item }}.prf"
    force: no
  with_items: "{{ groups['ndeployslaves'] }}"

- name: edit preference file
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/root/.unison/{{ item }}.prf"
    line: "root = ssh://root@{{item}}//home"
    regexp: '^root = ssh://'
  with_items: "{{ groups['ndeployslaves'] }}"
```

The contents of default.prf on your local host should be:

```
root = /home
root = ssh://
ignore = Path virtfs
ignore = Path */mail
```

However I have {{item}} working in a template. Are you sure your whitespace is correct? src and dest need to be indented one level deeper than template, but with_items needs to be on the same level as template.

```
- name: create the unison preference file
  template:
    src: default.prf.j2
    dest: "/root/.unison/{{ item }}.prf"
  with_items: "{{ groups['ndeployslaves'] }}"
```

Comment: same error. I even tried adding the item as a variable vars:
      the_host: "{{ item }}" and then referncing the_host in the j2 template which didnt help

Comment: Just edited my answer. I think I had a syntax error.

Comment: with_items: groups['ndeployslaves'] works fine and the item= shows correctly in debug .As I mentioned the things that need to work is having the value in the template file as a variable

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the issue now. You can't do what you are trying to in the way you are trying to do it, but I think I can come up with a solution

Comment: hmm...but as of 2014 it looks like this worked: https://ruin.io/2014/ansible-using-item-in-templates/

Comment: The link shows/gives my exact requirement .But somehow it does not seem to work for me !. Shows - FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112943/discussion-between-anoop-p-alias-and-smiller171).

Comment: was syntax (indentation) error. item works as mentioned in that article

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by an indentation error.
The `with_items: groups['ndeployslaves']` was indented a level deeper than it should have.